# The existence of a finite group with a given order and Sylow numbers?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Is there a finite group $G$ with order $6048=2^5.3^3.7$ satisfying the following three conditions:

1. The number $n_2(G)$ of Sylow $2$-subgroups is $189=3^3.7$;
2. The number $n_3(G)$ of Sylow $3$-subgroups is $112=2^4.7$;
3. The number $n_7(G)$ of Sylow $7$-subgroups is $288=2^5.3^2$?

I have tried to construct a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with small index, but I failed. Does someone have any methods to do this?

Comment: What did you try, exactly?

Comment: ${rm PSU}(3,3)$ has $n_2(G)=189$ and $n_7(G)=288$, but $n_3(G)=28$.

Comment: @Shaun, I just have used the method introduced by Issacs's book "Finite group theory" in pages 16-17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `grpconst` package in GAP to construct the groups of order 6048. There are 36021 isomorphism classes, of which 59 are not solvable.

None of the groups has $n_2=189$ and $n_3=112$.
Exactly one group, $PSU_3(3)$ (as @DerekHolt noted) has $n_2=189$ and $n_7=228$.

540 of the groups have $n_3=112$ (but none of them have $n_2=189$ or $n_7=228$).

Thus the answer to the question is ``no''.

Comment: May you give me any tutorials for how to use grpconst package in GAP to construct the groups of a given order? I have encounter a similar problem to construct the groups of order $25920$ with $n_2=405$ and $n_5=1296$.

Answer (score 0):

By https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_6048, $G$ is a solvable group, however, $288$ is not a solvable Sylow $7$-number, hence the answer is not.

Comment: Can we get $G$ is solvable by https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_6048? Is there a group of order 6048 which is neither simple nor solvable?

Comment: I fell in confused! We say $n=p_1^{a_1}\times ...\times p_n^{a_t}$ is a solvable Sylow $p$-number if $p_i^{a_i}-1$ is divided by $p$ for every $i=1, 2, ..., t$.

Comment: No, this web page does not show that the group would have to be solvable. There are 59  (up to isomorphism) groups of order 6048 that are not solvable. All but one of them also are not perfect.

Comment: @ahulpke, Thank you very much!